# Windows Store App failed Content Compliance - 6.2

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

How do I add "parental control features that require parental permission"? That's my question. My app failed content compliance - 6.2. I use Azure for a leader board that includes the name, DOB and country of the users of my app and for this reason the app has failed. As a side note this function is already in an app in the store, so unless the criteria have changed in the past six months I struggle to see how my existing release got certified.

However, the advice is to :

"6.2.2 If your app provides a user with uncontrolled: (i) access to online social networks, or (ii) sharing of personal information with third parties, including other gamers or online acquaintances, then you must assign it a Windows Store rating of at least 12+.  For such activity to be considered "controlled", your app must include parental control features that require parental permission to use such sharing features, and you must identify those and explain their functionality in the Notes to testers."

The notes from the tester state:

"The app appears to provide users with uncontrolled access to online social networks or sharing of personal information with third parties. Information about the users is being shared on the global leader board. Because of this, you must assign a Windows Store age rating of at least 12+."

My question therefore is does anyone have any advice on how to implement (or what is expected from MSFT) such parental control as the information in my failure report doesn't elaborate on this. Even if this can be implemented, given the tester's notes is this likely to satisfy the tester since the FAQ advice and tester advice differ. One says add parental control and the other says increase age rating to 12+?

I could change the rating, but since the app is for times tables, increasing it to 12 defeats the object since many children know their times tables by this age and I don't want to turn discourage potential users based on the age rating.

Many thanks in advance.

Jason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems to have been simple. Just provide a check box asking for parental consent to use the Internet for those people aged 12 and under. I added some descriptions in the help file to. Let's hope it gets certified now. Fingers crossed.